# MATLAB fitting of data to a inverse quadratic equation

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I have a bunch of data, and I want a fitting with a function that I want, for example, `1/(ax^2+bx+c)`. My objective is to get a,b,c values.

Is there any function of MATLAB that helps with this? I have been checking the `fit()` function, but I didn't reach a conclusion. Which is the best way?

Comment: Usually you want to fit the function to the data and not the other way around. ;) Concerning the functions: You might have a look at `fminunc` and `fminsearch`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The model you give can be solved using simple methods:

```
% model function
f = @(a,b,c,x) 1./(a*x.^2+b*x+c);

% noise function 
noise = @(z) 0.005*randn(size(z));

% parameters to find
a = +3;
b = +4;
c = -8;

% exmample data
x = -2:0.01:2;    x = x + noise(x);
y = f(a,b,c, x);  y = y + noise(y);


% create linear system Ax = b, with 
% A = [x²  x  1]
% x = [a; b; c]
% b = 1/y;
A = bsxfun(@power, x.', 2:-1:0);

A\(1./y.')
```

Result:

```
ans = 
 3.035753123094593e+00  % (a)
 4.029749103502019e+00  % (b)
-8.038644874704120e+00  % (c)
```

This is possible because the model you give is a linear one, in which case the backslash operator will give the solution (the `1./y` is a bit dangerous though...)

When fitting *non*-linear models, take a look at `lsqcurvefit` (optimization toolbox), or you can write your own implementation using `fmincon` (optimization toolbox),  `fminsearch` or `fminunc`.

Also, if you happen to have the curve fitting toolbox, type `help curvefit` and start there.

Comment: Hey thank! I have a problem. when using my data for x and y I have the next error which I don't understand: 'Non-singleton dimensions of the two input arrays must match each other.'
Also, I do have curvefit toolbox, but I can't find a proper function for what I want, only with the GUI! (yes, the GUI uses the other functions but I am lost there...)

Comment: @AnderBiguri: Hmm...seems you have more `y` data than `x` data (or vice versa). You'll have to see whether `numel(x)==numel(y)` and check if everything is transposed "correctly". If `numel(x)~=numel(y)`, well...that's not something I can solve :)

Comment: @AnderBiguri that is probably a transposition problem with the `bsxfun` arguments. First vector should be a column vector, second one - a row vector.

Comment: @angainor that is exactly the problem, both data are row vector! thanks! But when transposing one of them I get error in the last line, A\... Matrix dimensions must agree.

Comment: well,I solved it eliminating the transpose of Y in the last line! thanks both !

Answer (score 1):

To me this sounds like a least squares problem.

I think `lsqcurvefit` might be a good place to start:

http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/optim/ug/lsqcurvefit.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether this post is useful after 3 months or not.
i think `cftool` may help you
check it

easily you can add data and select fitting method ....